# SQL query to structure data in a particular format

Tags: sql, hive

I have a data in the below format.

```
ID month subid val1 val2
1  200411 a     10   20
1  200411 b     15   25 
2  200411 x     9    12  
2  200411 y     15   30
2  200411 z     50   11
```

Can you please tell me how I can write a query to convert this to the below format.

```
ID month subid  val1_1 val1_2 val1_3  val2_1  val2_2 val3_3 
1  200411 a,b   10     15     null    20      25     null
2  200411 x,y,z 9      15     50      12      30     11
```

Please let me know if you have questions. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is a huge dataset. What I have above is a sample data. The number of columns in the output data need to be dynamic depending on how many subids the ID has for a particular month. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select id, month, collect_set(subid) as subids,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val1 end) as val1_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val1 end) as val1_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val1 end) as val1_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val2 end) as val2_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val2 end) as val2_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val2 end) as val2_3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by subid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

`collect_set()` returns an array.  That seems more useful than a string, but you can convert it to a string representation if you like.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you. Is there any way I can do this without collect_set(). I am using a version of HIVE that does not support this function.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get the string representation without using collect_set()?

Comment: @SawanS . . . Hive 0.13.0 was released in 2014.  Your version is very old.  It is not simple to do in such an old version.